# semver: matching a pre-release suffix (3.* =/= 3.4.5-1)

Tags: semantic-versioning

Using this online semver checker: https://jubianchi.github.io/semver-check/

Notice how

version "3.4.5" is compatible with expression "3.*"
[image]
but...
[image]
version "3.4.5-1" is **NOT** compatible with expression "3.*"

How can I change my compatibility expression to include this pre-release version?

Comment: "*A pre-release version indicates that the version is unstable and might not satisfy the intended compatibility requirements as denoted by its associated normal version.*"

Comment: All goofy range notations, are not part of the [semver standard](https://semver.org). To be a valid semver checker, it can validate syntax and compare less/greater than or equal to any pair of version strings (sort order). In your case, all version strings with a prerelease tag have lower precedence than all version strings that do not have a prerelease tag and 3.* is NOT a semver version string.

Answer (score 6):

That's because pre-release versions are not included by default.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/Masterminds/semver#working-with-prerelease-versions):

> SemVer comparisons without a pre-release comparator will skip pre-release versions. For example, >=1.2.3 will skip pre-releases when looking at a list of releases while >=1.2.3-0 will evaluate and find pre-releases.

In order to match that pre-release version, you could use, for example: `~3 >3.4.5-0`.

> 3.4.5-1 satisfies constraint ~3 >3.4.5-0